# Disabling alt key to avoid flash freeze

Tags: c#, keypress

I'm working on an application that uses webbrowser control. The site I'm acessing in the webbrowser uses flash and when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> the flash freezes. I want to disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to avoid this situation. I researched a lot about this but I didn't have found any concrete answer yet.

Comment: You could look into autohotkey, and remap the alt key to do nothing.  You probably want to do this based on the program name or the currently active window title.

Comment: Since it is in your own program, you could look at handling keypress, look at keyup / key down events.

Comment: Instead, you should figure out why it's freezing and fix that.

Comment: @SLaks That's why I mencioned the freezes. I looked for that in the internet: nothing.

Comment: What's the url of the site for test?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Hey Reza, this an old question. I've already figured this out. Thanks.

Comment: Good job, so if you think the answer may be useful for future readers, post it here, but if you think it was a special case which can not be useful for future readers you can delete the question .

Comment: @RezaAghaei I handled the Alt key with the code you provided me :D